# Autolayout UIScrollView Constraints

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I know this has been asked thousand of times. I have followed all the guidelines but still not able to get it right.

Here are my constraints (Adding it programmatically)

1. `ScrollView`: top/bottom/left/right anchors set to view anchors with 0 constant.
2. Added `ContainerView` inside `ScrollView`
3. `ContainerView` (`UIView`): top/bottom/left/right/centerX/centerY anchors set to `scrollView` anchors with 0 constant
4. Added `ContentView` (`UIView`) inside `ContainerView`
5. `ContentView`: top/left/right constraints to `ContainerView` with some constant.
6. Added `dummyView` (`UIView`) inside `ContentView`
7. `dummyView`: top/left/right/bottom constraints to `ContentView` with some constant. height anchor with constant value set to 1200 (Random Number).

View layout properly with no warnings or error but does not scroll to bottom.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Number 3 is wrong.

Comment: @Desdenova What should be constraints set to ContentView?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `contentLayoutGuide` property in `UIScrollView`, about which the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865870-contentlayoutguide) states the following:

> Use this layout guide when you want to create Auto Layout constraints related to the content area of a scroll view.

To get a dynamic height based on autolayout constraints, you would set the `widthAnchor` of the content view to the `widthAnchor` of the [frameLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865772-framelayoutguide) property.

Expressed in Swift code, this might look something like this:

```
static private func constraint(contentView: UIView, scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let layoutGuide = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor),
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)
    ])
}
```

Finally, a complete self-contained example, as requested in the comments, now with a multi-line `UILabel`. It uses a long dummy text - you can remove it and add just one word instead of the long text and it would still work. The reason for this is that the content view can be any size. Of course, with a larger `UIScrollView`, you can't scroll if the content view is small. The important thing - as generally with autolayout constraints if you want to have dynamic sizes - is that you have to define the constraints all the way from top to bottom or left to right.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let contentView = UIView()
    private let label = UILabel()
    
    static private func constraint(view: UIView, to: UIView, constant: CGFloat) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: constant),
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: constant),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -constant),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: to.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -constant)
        ])
    }
    
    static private func constraint(contentView: UIView, scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let layoutGuide = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text =
        """
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu. Eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus. Et tortor consequat id porta. Vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Mollis aliquam ut porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla.

        Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus. Lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Sit amet dictum sit amet. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus. Fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus nulla at. Tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales.

        Quam id leo in vitae turpis. Diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra. Nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar. Aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum. Ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna.

        Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. At lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra. In cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi. Nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper. Ornare lectus sit amet est. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit.
        """
        
        Self.constraint(view: scrollView, to: view, constant: 0)
        Self.constraint(contentView: contentView, scrollView: scrollView)
        Self.constraint(view: label, to: contentView, constant: 16)
    }

}
```

Comment: It works when there is fixed height. I have label inside contentView which does not have fixed height. In this scenario scrollView throws content size ambiguous error. Can you also help me with that?

Comment: @MayankKhursija I updated the answer to remove the fixed height view and added a multi-line label instead. You can then replace the long dummy text with a single word, for example, and it would still work without being ambiguous because the content view can be any size. The most important thing is that you need to define the constraints all the way from top to bottom or left to right if you want to have dynamic autolayout dimensions. I also removed the container view from the answer because it is actually redundant. Hope this helps.